# Is there a shorthand for assigning from $1...$n after matching in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a shorthand for the following ruby fragment:

```
var = 'foo 123  456  789   bar';

var =~ /^foo +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +bar$/;

first=$1
second=$2
third=$3
```

It seems to me that there is certainly something like `(first, second, third) = ....` but I have no idea with what term I could go looking for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `match` instead of `=~`, you get back a `MatchData` object, which has a method `captures`, which returns the values matched by the capturing groups in an array:

```
first, second, third = var.match(/.../).captures
```

Comment: Several days ago I used `match` in Ruby at first time. It was exactly this purpose )

Comment: Note that this has the problem that if the match fails, `#match` returns `nil`, and `nil.captures` isn't so hot (unlike `nil.to_a`).

Comment: Who's ever heard of a match failing? I mean, everyone raise their hand who's written a bad pattern... huh... one, two... oh... everyone. :-)

Comment: @Greg, it has not to be bad to be unmatched.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, which you can go:

```
var = 'foo 123  456  789   bar'
/^foo +(?<first>\d+) +(?<second>\d+) +(?<third>\d+) +bar$/ =~ var
```

This assigns captures to local variables automatically.
Note: `str =~ regexp` will not work here. Only `regexp =~ str`.

As far as I know, it's an Oniguruma engine feature, so it works in 1.9
http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Regexp.html#M001100

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'foo 123  456  789   bar'
re  = /^foo +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +bar$/
p re.match(str).to_a
#=> ["foo 123  456  789   bar", "123", "456", "789"]

_, a, b, c = re.match(str).to_a
p [a,b,c]
#=> ["123", "456", "789"]
```

Note that `Regex#match` will return `nil` if no match is found, but `nil.to_a` returns an empty array, so the above is safe.

Comment: If you're ok with an exception being thrown for no match, you can do `a, b, c = re.match(str)[1..-1]`