# Protecting against an undefined chained method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, undefined, null

I have a long loop that results in this:

```
csv_code = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["Product ID","Name", "Url"]
  @all_products.each do |product|
      if product.page_url("en_US") != nil
      turl = product.page_url("en_US")
      end
    csv << [product.name,product.d_id, turl]
  end
end
```

The method uses products 1-17 works great resulting in a url printed. When I get to my 18th record I have problems

```
Product.find(18) // product found!
product.find(18).page_url("en_US")
NoMethodError: undefined method `page_url' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I protect against these undefined events?

url = product.page_url("en_US")

Comment: product.find(18) ? "random events"? I don't get it.

Comment: When I have an undefined method, I need to protect against it so the loop continues.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565496/ruby-syntactic-sugar-dealing-with-nils. May advice: ick's maybe.

Comment: The issue is that a `product` is `nil`: "undefined method 'page_url' for nil:NilClass". Solution: Make sure `product` can't be `nil` (this may be a deeper issue, but it's easy to filter out -- consider `Enumerable.select` of `if product && product.page_url ...`, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that a `product` is `nil`:

> > undefined method 'page_url' for nil:NilClass". Solution:

(It has *nothing* to do with `page_url` *maybe* returning `nil`.)

Make sure `product` can't be `nil`: but be wary that this may be a deeper issue. In any case, "fixing" this issue is easy to deal with.

Consider either using a collection restriction (such as [Enumerable#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001489)):

```
@all_products.reject(&:nil?).each do {
   ...
}
```

The above uses the [Symbol#to_proc "Rails magic"](http://www.sitepoint.com/insta-block-with-symbolto_proc/), but could just as easily have been `{|x| x.nil?}` as the restriction. The downside is it's not practical to use this for a "no URL" condition per-product although [Enumerable#partition](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001496) could help with that: use the right tool for the job.

Another solution is to expand the conditional check itself:

```
if product && product.page_url("en_US")
   # yay
else
   # uhm
end
```

The short-circuit nature of `&&` will ensure `page_url` is only invoked upon a truthy value (which excludes `nil`).

I also took the liberty of assuming `page_url` can't return `false` as I find this makes the intent more clear.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
product.find(18).try(:page_url, "en_US")
```

But it's a perf killer.

Are you sure `Product.find(18)` doesn't return `nil` ?

Anyway, you could do:

```
url = product.nil? ? "no_url" : product.page_url("en_US")
```

Comment: the problem is the locale is "en_CA"

Comment: ok so `try` should be ok but what you wrote in your question doesn't lead to this conclusion